# Basemap projection seems to change with zoom level

Tags: qgis, zoom, basemap, quickmapservices

I have imported a point vector layer which is in `ESPG:4326 - WGS 84` containing points from all over the world, and added the `OSM Standard` basemap from the `QuickMapServices` plugin.

When zoomed out, I notice that the basemap does not align with the point layer. However, when I zoom in, the basemap changes and the points do align properly.

See example image below - zoomed out on the left, points in Iceland and along the coast of Greenland do not line up with basemap. Zooming in just slightly on the right, the basemap re-renders and now the points align properly.

The same thing occurs for other basemaps from `QuickMapServices` - Google, CartoDB etc.

How can I get the basemap to align even when the map is zoomed out?

[image: Zoom comparison]

Comment: Try put them on the surface, I think they look off because they're a long way up... you haven't got the vertical measurements in feet have you?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I don't think there is any `z` data - the layer came from a delimited text file which only had `x` and `y`.

Comment: I've now checked on QGIS on another machine using the same data, and this problem does not occur. Must be something wrong with the other machine.